# Custom error bars on bar chart with multiple series

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have this graph, and I want to add custom error bars. I have the 95% confidence intervals for each data point, but when I add the values for a single bar, it automatically adds to all other bars in the same series.

All I want each bar to have it's own and separate error bars. [please click here to see my lovely graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YFiG.jpg)  Is that so hard?!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your series has four points. Put the four error bar values into a 1x4 or 4x1 range (or two such ranges if positive and negative are different). Select this whole range to apply the four values to the positive error bars for the series, and again for the negative error bars.

Repeat for the other series.